# Trouble understanding purpose of second $($ in $q(x_k(x_{k-1}^i,z_k)$

Tags: probability

I'm reading a piece on tracking algorithms and particle filters in particular, and stumbled upon the equation: $q(x_k(x_{k-1}^i,z_k)$. I think I understand most of the equation, but I can't understand what the second $($ is doing in the equation (the one between $x_k$ and $x_{k-1}$).

For reference, [A Tutorial on Particle Filters for Online
Nonlinear/Non-Gaussian Bayesian Tracking
M. Sanjeev Arulampalam, Simon Maskell, Neil Gordon, and Tim Clapp](http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~pabbeel/cs287-fa12/optreadings/Arulampalam_etal_2002.pdf), page 179, equation 52.

Comment: Does it make sense for it to be a typo for $q(x_k\mid x_{k-1}^i,z_k)$?

Comment: I figured it would make the most sense if it were a typo, but later there is an equation $p(z_k|x_k(x_{k-1}^i)$, and if I were to replace the second $($ with a bar there, it would make no sense anymore, would it?

Comment: x @Afs: Well, if we assume an editing process where a bar could conceivably turn into a parenthesis (such as OCR or a typist who doesn't understand the math), the same process could probably also turn a comma into parenthesis for the latter example).

Comment: Unbalanced parentheses are always a bad sign.  I see there is also $p(x_k | x_{0:k-1}|z_{1:k-1})$ in the second line of equation (45).  I have no idea what the authors mean by that.  Maybe you should ask them?

Comment: Thanks for the reactions guys, I'll assume Henning his answer makes the most sense, and I'm going to assume they ment a comma everywhere the 'weird' bars or parentheses appear. Thanks for the help!